# Is there a better way to generate 5 million csv files quickly

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I would like to create 5 million csv files, I have waiting for almost 3 hours, but the program is still running. Can somebody give me some advice, how to speed up the file generation.

After these 5 million files generation complete, I have to upload them to s3 bucket.

It would be better if someone know how to generate these files through AWS, thus, we can move files to s3 bucket directly and ignore network speed issue.(Just start to learning AWS, there are lots of knowledge need to know)

The following is my code.

```
public class ParallelCsvGenerate implements Runnable {
    private static AtomicLong baseID = new AtomicLong(8160123456L);
    private static ThreadLocalRandom random = ThreadLocalRandom.current();
    private static ThreadLocalRandom random2 = ThreadLocalRandom.current();
    private static String filePath = "C:\\5millionfiles\\";
    private static List<String> headList = null;
    private static String csvHeader = null;
    public ParallelCsvGenerate() {
        headList = generateHeadList();
        csvHeader = String.join(",", headList);
    }


    @Override
    public void run() {
        for(int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
            generateCSV();
        }s
    }


    private void generateCSV() {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append(csvHeader).append(System.lineSeparator());
        for (int i = 0; i < headList.size(); i++) {
            if(i < headList.size() - 1) {
                builder.append(i % 2 == 0 ? generateRandomInteger() : generateRandomStr()).append(",");
            } else {
                builder.append(i % 2 == 0 ? generateRandomInteger() : generateRandomStr());
            }
        }


        String fileName = String.valueOf(baseID.addAndGet(1));
        File csvFile = new File(filePath + fileName + ".csv");
        FileWriter fileWriter = null;
        try {
            fileWriter = new FileWriter(csvFile);
            fileWriter.write(builder.toString());
            fileWriter.flush();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e);
        } finally {
            try {
                if(fileWriter != null) {
                    fileWriter.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }




    private static List<String> generateHeadList() {
        List<String> headList = new ArrayList<>(20);
        String baseFiledName = "Field";
        for(int i = 1; i <=20; i++) {
            headList.add(baseFiledName + i);
        }
        return headList;
    }




    /**
     * generate a number in range of 0-50000
     * @return
     */
    private Integer generateRandomInteger() {
        return random.nextInt(0,50000);
    }




    /**
     * generate a string length is 5 - 8
     * @return
     */
    private String generateRandomStr() {
        int strLength = random2.nextInt(5, 8);
        String str="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
        int length = str.length();
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < strLength; i++) {
            builder.append(str.charAt(random.nextInt(length)));
        }
        return builder.toString();
    }
```

Main

```
ParallelCsvGenerate generate = new ParallelCsvGenerate();


Thread a = new Thread(generate, "A");
Thread b = new Thread(generate, "B");
Thread c = new Thread(generate, "C");
Thread d = new Thread(generate, "D");
Thread e = new Thread(generate, "E");

a.run();
b.run();
c.run();
d.run();
e.run();
```

Thanks for your guys advice, just refactor the code, and generate 3.8million files using 2.8h, which is much better.
Refactor code:

```
public class ParallelCsvGenerate implements Callable<Integer> {
    private static String filePath = "C:\\5millionfiles\\";
    private static String[] header = new String[]{
            "FIELD1","FIELD2","FIELD3","FIELD4","FIELD5",
            "FIELD6","FIELD7","FIELD8","FIELD9","FIELD10",
            "FIELD11","FIELD12","FIELD13","FIELD14","FIELD15",
            "FIELD16","FIELD17","FIELD18","FIELD19","FIELD20",
    };
    private String fileName;
    public ParallelCsvGenerate(String fileName) {
        this.fileName = fileName;
    }

    @Override
    public Integer call() throws Exception {
        try {
            generateCSV();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return 0;
    }

    private void generateCSV() throws IOException {

        CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(filePath + fileName + ".csv"), CSVWriter.DEFAULT_SEPARATOR, CSVWriter.NO_QUOTE_CHARACTER);
        String[] content = new String[]{
                RandomGenerator.generateRandomInteger(),
                RandomGenerator.generateRandomStr(),
                RandomGenerator.generateRandomInteger(),
                RandomGenerator.generateRandomStr(),
                RandomGenerator.generateRandomInteger(),
                RandomGenerator.generateRandomStr(),
                RandomGenerator.generateRandomInteger(),
                RandomGenerator.generateRandomStr(),
                RandomGenerator.generateRandomInteger(),
                RandomGenerator.generateRandomStr(),
                RandomGenerator.generateRandomInteger(),
                RandomGenerator.generateRandomStr(),
                RandomGenerator.generateRandomInteger(),
                RandomGenerator.generateRandomStr(),
                RandomGenerator.generateRandomInteger(),
                RandomGenerator.generateRandomStr(),
                RandomGenerator.generateRandomInteger(),
                RandomGenerator.generateRandomStr(),
                RandomGenerator.generateRandomInteger(),
                RandomGenerator.generateRandomStr()
        };
        writer.writeNext(header);
        writer.writeNext(content);
        writer.close();
    }

}
```

Main

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Start generate");
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        ThreadPoolExecutor threadPoolExecutor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(8, 8,
                0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,
                new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>());
        List<ParallelCsvGenerate> taskList = new ArrayList<>(3800000);
        for(int i = 0; i < 3800000; i++) {
            taskList.add(new ParallelCsvGenerate(i+""));
        }
        try {
            List<Future<Integer>> futures = threadPoolExecutor.invokeAll(taskList);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Success");
        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Using time: " + (end-start));
    }
```

Comment: Use multiple processes over multiple machines

Comment: Show us your `main`. Do you create multiple instances of `ParallelCsvGenerate` and run them in separate threads?

Comment: main is simple, I just create one instance, and 5 threads to run

Answer (score 0):

1. You could write directly into the file (without allocating the whole file in one StringBuilder). (I think this is the **biggest** time+memory **bottleneck** here: `builder.toString()`)
2. You could generate each file in parallel.
3. (little tweaks:) Omit the if's inside loop.

   `if(i < headList.size() - 1)` is not needed, when you do a more clever loop + 1 extra iteration.

   The `i % 2 == 0` can be eliminated by a better iteration (`i+=2`) ..and more labor inside the loop (`i -> int, i + 1 -> string`)
4. If applicable prefer `append(char)` to `append(String)`. (Better `append(',')` than `append(",")`!)

...

Comment: thanks for your advice. for 1, how to write the content into file directly? Will using CsvWriter be helpful? for 2, how to generate each file in parallel?

Comment: I/O being the bottleneck, parallelization won't help. Point 1 is the issue.

Comment: You have to "little refactor", and use the FileWriter wherever StringBuilder is used, GBMan. CsvWriter sounds also ok/suitable/on-the-fly! ..in parallel, you already seem to do/see Kayaman's comment: point 1 is important/costs much time!

Answer (score -1):

You can use Fork/Join  framework (java 7 and above) to make your process in parallel and use multi core of your Cpu.
I'll take an example for you.

```
import java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool;
import java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask;
import java.util.concurrent.RecursiveTask;
import java.util.stream.LongStream;

public class ForkJoinAdd extends RecursiveTask<Long> {

    private final long[] numbers;
    private final int start;
    private final int end;
    public static final long threshold = 10_000;

    public ForkJoinAdd(long[] numbers) {
        this(numbers, 0, numbers.length);
    }

    private ForkJoinAdd(long[] numbers, int start, int end) {
        this.numbers = numbers;
        this.start = start;
        this.end = end;
    }

    @Override
    protected Long compute() {

        int length = end - start;
        if (length <= threshold) {
            return add();
        }

        ForkJoinAdd firstTask = new ForkJoinAdd(numbers, start, start + length / 2);
        firstTask.fork(); //start asynchronously

        ForkJoinAdd secondTask = new ForkJoinAdd(numbers, start + length / 2, end);

        Long secondTaskResult = secondTask.compute();
        Long firstTaskResult = firstTask.join();

        return firstTaskResult + secondTaskResult;

    }

    private long add() {
        long result = 0;
        for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
            result += numbers[i];
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static long startForkJoinSum(long n) {
        long[] numbers = LongStream.rangeClosed(1, n).toArray();
        ForkJoinTask<Long> task = new ForkJoinAdd(numbers);
        return new ForkJoinPool().invoke(task);
    }

}
```

use [this example](https://mkyong.com/java/java-fork-join-framework-examples/)
And if you want to read more about it, [Guide to the Fork/Join Framework in Java | Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/java-fork-join)
and [Fork/Join (The Java™ Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/forkjoin.html) 
can help you to better understand and better design your app.
be lucky.

Comment: @Kayaman 5 million files is not that much. Also each file seems to be below one kilobyte in size.

Comment: @ciamej you don't seem to understand what it means that the work is I/O bound.

Comment: @Kayaman Creating 5 million files on a modern computer with an SSD drive should take a few minutes at most.

Comment: @ciamej I know. Unless you do it wrong. So stop giving wrong advice about multithreading for I/O bound work.

Comment: @Kayaman I guess you mean to use asynchornous I/O, but then does `filewriter.flush` really work synchronously?

Comment: @ciamej you should stop guessing. There's really nothing special about writing CSV, but you really want to make it complicated.

Comment: @Kayaman I was always under impression that java *does not* guarantee synchronous disk writes. I tried googling now and haven't found any confirmation that `flush` guarantees the writes to be persisted. The only problem I can see that each `flush` or `close` involves a syscall, but still 5 million syscalls is not that much. Please enlighten us what is your point exactly.

Comment: @Kayaman I've just run the code on my laptop: 1 thread -> 4k files/s, 4 threads -> 10k files/s, 8 threads -> 15k files/s (I have 4 physical cores and hyperthreading). How do you explain that? Multithreading won't help?

Answer (score -1):

- Remove the `for(int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)` loop from `run` method (leave a single `generateCSV()` call.
- Create 5 million `ParallelCsvGenerate` objects.
- Submit them to a `ThreadPoolExecutor`

Converted `main`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {    
    ThreadPoolExecutor ex = (ThreadPoolExecutor) Executors.newFixedThreadPool(8);
    for(int i = 0; i < 5000000; i++) {
        ParallelCsvGenerate generate = new ParallelCsvGenerate();
        ex.submit(generate);
    }
    ex.shutdown();
}
```

It takes roughly 5 minutes to complete on my laptop (4 physical cores with hyperthreading, SSD drive).

**EDIT:**

I've replaced `FileWriter` with `AsynchronousFileChannel` using the following code:

```
    Path file = Paths.get(filePath + fileName + ".csv");
    try(AsynchronousFileChannel asyncFile = AsynchronousFileChannel.open(file,
                        StandardOpenOption.WRITE,
                        StandardOpenOption.CREATE)) {

        asyncFile.write(ByteBuffer.wrap(builder.toString().getBytes()), 0);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

to achieve 30% speedup.

I believe that the main bottleneck is the hard drive and filesystem itself. Not much more can be achieved here.

Comment: create 5 million instances will need a huge memory, I don think my laptop can handle this situation. it may OOM

Comment: @GBMan 5 million instances will consume only a handful megabytes of RAM.

Comment: @GBMan Does your laptop have an SSD drive? If not that could be the bottleneck.

Comment: @GBMan in Linux you could create a so called RAM disk, a special volume that resides completely in RAM, writing to that destination would be much faster.

Comment: @GBMan I just run your code on my laptop (without any changes). It produces around 5 thousand files per second. If I let it run, it would take 20 minutes to complete. I guess there is nothing wrong with your code. I believe your laptop is too slow.

Comment: @GBMan I converted the code to use fixed thread pool of size 8 (the number of cores on my laptop with hyperthreading). I was able to generate 15k files per second. The program would complete in roughly 5 minutes.

Comment: thanks for your advice, I take your advice and refactor the code, find it is much better. By the way, I just tried your code, and find out the file generation speed it almost the same as my refactor code's. 300 files per second. I think I need to buy a new laptop